# Rename 'recording' tag to 'audio-recording'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup, retag-request

We have tags for [video-recording](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-recording), [voice-recording](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-recording), [call-recording](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-recording), and 'screen-recording' (synonym to [screencast](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screencast)). I suggest to rename [recording](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recording) to [audio-recording](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording) to match that list (I'm already cleaning up the queue, re-tagging Qs belonging to the others) and to avoid ambiguity.

Optionally, 'recording' could become a synonym; but I'd rather say we let it "die hard".

Comment: First, is there a meaningful difference between `audio-recording` and `voice-recording`?  The latter could be synonymized under the former.

Comment: Yes, there is (at least to me). "voice-recording" to me means "dictaphone" and the like ("lower quality" if you want to say so, and "spoken voice"), usually done via the microphone -- while "audio-recording" rather includes the recording of audio-streams, music (as opposed to "spoken word") etc. and suggests "higher quality". I could go over the tags, check their Qs, re-tag where necessary, and set up fitting tag wikis to make the difference clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[recording](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recording) should no longer be used; I've retagged the handful of questions that were using it with more specific variants to disambiguate it. It is not a synonym of anything at the moment since the more specific tags will appear in the tag autocomplete anyway.

Comment: Hm, somebody seems to have created the 'audio-recording' tag (meanwhile) -- so well, everything fine with me :) Thanks!

Comment: That was me. It seemed like it made the most sense, as you suggested.